# How to combine multiple columns in one array in Presto

Tags: sql, presto, trino

Suppose we have a table

```
|           Array1         |           Array2          |
| ------------------------ | ------------------------- |
|         0.99993938       |         1.88473736        |
|         4.66993938       |         10.7473736        |
```

How do combine these column values into one array.

Expected result:

```
|                  Array3                 | 
| --------------------------------------- |
|         [0.99993938, 1.88473736]        |
|         [4.66993938, 10.7473736]        |
```

I tried
`select concat(Array1, Array2) from table`
It does the job, but without the commas and it neglects the decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an [`array`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/language/types.html#array) you can do the following:

```sql
select array[Column1, Column2]
from table;
```